# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.Contact

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, classnotfoundexception

I created a Dynamic Web Project, i am using a mysql jdbc driver to connect with db but when i deploy app i get the following error

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Detyra] class or package not found
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1344)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1127)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1006)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitService.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitService.java:143)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitService.start(PersistenceUnitService.java:77)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.Contact from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @37f8bb67 (roots: E:\jboss-as-7.0.1.Final\modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:330)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:101)
```

Comment: So, where's that class then?

Comment: Do you want to see the code or the path of the class ?

Comment: Exception clearly tells that Java can't find that class anywhere. Thus Java couldn't even come to the point to figure out the class' contents. Therefore, its contents is irrelevant to the problem. You'd have had still exactly the same problem when you change the class' contents.

Comment: The class Contact which JVM cant find is inside one of my packages. I have no idea why jvm wouldnt be able to find a class. I have a lot of other classes but java complains only for this one.

Comment: Another thing that i forgot to mention, this class is an entity, i declare it in Persistence.xml file.

Comment: It could be just a typo or a wrong location or a dirty build; Yes that was already clear from stack trace.